# Autowired , Value annotation is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, postconstruct

I am using below class and my @Autowired, @Value annotation is not working for spring boot application. Also, I use init method with @PostConstruct and initialize the value when the application starts. Then right before use of the variables, the value gets intialized to 0 or null.

Here is my code:

```
@Component
public class OsmXmlClient {
    
    private static final Logger log = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(OsmXmlClient.class);

    /*@Value("${osm.xml.service.url}") */
    private String osmXmlServiceUrl = "http://myurl/XMLAPI";
    /*#@Value("${osm.xml.service.userId}") */
    private String osmXmlServiceUserId = "abc";
    /*@Value("${osm.xml.service.password}")*/
    private String osmXmlServicePassword = "abc123";
    
    private Map<Integer, String> urlMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int seviceUrlsCount = 0;
    
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        List<String> servieUrlList = Arrays.asList(osmXmlServiceUrl.split(";"));
        log.info("servieUrlList = " + servieUrlList);
        seviceUrlsCount = servieUrlList.size();
        log.info("seviceUrlsCount in init = " + seviceUrlsCount);
        
        for(int i=0;i<seviceUrlsCount;i++) {
            log.info("servieUrlList.get(i) = " + servieUrlList.get(i));
            urlMap.put(i, servieUrlList.get(i));
        }
    } 
    
    private String getServiceUrl() {
        log.info("serviceUrlsCount  at getServiceUrl = " + seviceUrlsCount);
        return urlMap.get(random.nextInt(seviceUrlsCount));
    }
}
```

Here is the log:

```
[2020-07-31 17:07:30.373] [INFO] [Context:TomcatWebServer] [] [Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9014 (http)]
[2020-07-31 17:07:30.903] [DEBUG] [Context:OsmModuleApplication] [] [osmProperties = OsmProperties()]
[2020-07-31 17:07:30.920] [INFO] [Context:OsmXmlClient] [] [servieUrlList = [http://myurl/XMLAPI]]
[2020-07-31 17:07:30.921] [INFO] [Context:OsmXmlClient] [] [seviceUrlsCount in init = 1]
[2020-07-31 17:07:30.921] [INFO] [Context:OsmXmlClient] [] [servieUrlList.get(i) = http://myurl/XMLAPI]
[2020-07-31 17:07:31.041] [INFO] [Context:OrderController] [] [OrderControllerInit called]
```

Then I got this log:

```
[2020-07-31 17:07:45.403] [INFO] [Context:OrderDetailsService] [] [Entering 
retryOrderService with billerorderId = 22428040]
[2020-07-31 17:07:45.403] [INFO] [Context:OsmXmlClient] [] [serviceUrlsCount  at getServiceUrl = 0]
[2020-
```

I had experienced the @Autowired and @Value annotation issue before . But I had a workaround. I would like to know why this is hapenning and what the solution to it is.

Here is my service class that call OsmXmlClient class:

```
@Service
public class OrderDetailsService {

    private static final Logger log = 
    LoggerFactory.getLogger(OrderDetailsService.class);

    OSMClient osmClient = new OSMClient();
    OsmXmlClient osmXmlClient = new OsmXmlClient();
    OSMProvAdService provAdService = new OSMProvAdService();
    CommonService commonService = new CommonService();

    public RetryOrderResponseType retryOrderService(String orderId) {
        log.info("Entering retryOrderService with billerorderId = " + orderId);
    
        String billerOrderId = "";
    
        String orderProcessHistory = osmXmlClient.queryOrder(orderId);
        log.info("orderProcessHistory = " + orderProcessHistory);
    
        RetryOrderResponseType retryOrderResponse = null;
        List<GetOrderResponseType> orderResponseTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        FindOrderResponseType findOrderResponseType = null;
    
        return retryOrderResponse;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have to instatiate using new keyword instead of Autowiring.

Comment: Show the class where you are calling this service.

Comment: I added OrderDetailsService class in my post that calls OsmXmlClient.

Comment: where is the config file that contains `osm.xml.service.url`?

Comment: It is application.yml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Value properties are not initialized by Spring unless the component is initialized by Spring. Do not instantiate classes with `new` yourself if you want dependency injection, property injection et cetera to work. Instead, use @Autowired to supply instances of your `Component`.